# how to display latest uploaded products first in category page in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

Can anyone tell me how to change the display order on the category page in opencart? My products are being displayed in reverse chronological order (oldest products first) and I would like newest products to display first. I have read several posts but cannot find a good answer. I'm sure it's something simple but I cannot figure it out.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

i tried below code but not get any result.

Default sortorder is: `p.sort_order ASC`

Edit catalog/controller/product/category.php.

Find:

```
$sort = 'p.sort_order';
```

Change into:

```
$sort = 'p.date_added';
```

Again Find:

```
$order = 'ASC';
```

Change into:

```
$order = 'DESC';
```

To set it as default sorting:
Change:

```
'value' => 'p.sort_order-ASC',
```

Into:

```
'value' => 'p.date_added-DESC',
```

Here i can't get any result after change like this. I tried so many times but not found. Can any one please help me on this Opencart category page.

Comment: Where is your query code? Show us what you are doing to get the data.

Comment: Your question has little to no chances of being successfully answered. Provide some code, screenshot perhaps - anything that you think will help us understand what you mean.

Comment: edited my code please check

Answer (score 1):

Provide the query code please.

But i think you want something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (your table name) ORDER BY id ASC;
```

it's simple as that. This query will display the newest created products.